# Can I return null for hibernate transaction methods?

Tags: hibernate

Actually i have method with @Transactional annotation which was returing null then at run time it was giving null pointer exception.But instead of sending null object i have created an empty object.So now it is working.So could you please explain how it is working?

Comment: If you want us to explain why some code works or doesn't, you have to show the code, and give us your inputs, actual outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I am calling  getCIADataJourney method like this:accountList = getCIADataJourney(notifyObjectResponse.getKeySearchName(), null, notifyObjectResponse.getAccountIds()).getAccount(); This is the signature of getCIADataJourney method:@Transactional(value = "gsTxManager", readOnly = false)
 public CIADataGrid getCIADataJourney(String journeyId, CIADataGrid ciaDataGrid, List<String> notifyAccountIds).When getCIADataJourney is returning null then it is throwing null pointer exception where i am calling this function if i will use new CIADataGrid() then it is working fine.